# Pandas dataframe multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following code is working

`c1 = da['A']<=50 c2 = da['A']>=35 df = da[c1 & c2]['B']`

But how can I write this in one line?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by conditions and by column label:

```
df = da.loc[(da['A']<=50) & (da['A']>=35), 'B']
```

Your solution should be changed, but not recommended, because [evaluation order matters](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters) - possible chained assignment with `SettingWithCopyWarning`, if assign value by mask (what is similar code like here):

```
df = da[(da['A']<=50) & (da['A']>=35)]['B']
```

Comment: What is the differences between both methods. Which one is the favorite to use?

Comment: @jpen - First is best use,  I try explain why not second use. For select both working well, but if assign (very similar code `da.loc[(da['A']<=50) & (da['A']>=35), 'B'] = 10` vs `da[(da['A']<=50) & (da['A']>=35)]['B'] = 10`, first working well, second raise error.